# In javafx, how does one make methods done in event handlers affect the rest of the code?

Tags: java, javafx

Basically my code is like this:

```
 fileOpener.setOnAction(
                new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                    @Override
                    public void handle(final ActionEvent e) {
                            myFileList.add(openMusicTracks.showOpenDialog(window));
System.out.println(myFileList.getName(0)); //prints file name so I know this works
                    }
                });
```

I want the add method (that's inside of the EventHandler) to actually edit the arraylist for everywhere else so that later when I reference it in

```
ObservableList<String> playList = FXCollections.observableArrayList ();
            for(int i = 0; i < myFileList.size(); i++) {
            playList.add(i, myFileList.get(i).getName());
System.out.println(myFileList.getName(0)); //doesn't print the file name, so I know this doesn't work.
        }
```

the arraylist won't be empty. How do I do this? I'm sorry if there's a more elegant way to word this, but I have honestly no idea how to research this, I've tried. Thanks.

Comment: What is the problem with your current code? Just make your arraylist accessible to both button's event handler and the for loop.

Comment: What exactly do you not believe?

Comment: Sorry, I pressed enter thinking it would give me another line, but how exactly do I make it accessible? The arraylist is a state variable, and they're both in the same class if that helps

Comment: I have an added a solution, which explains what I said before.

Answer (score 0):

A simple example which shows how can an ArrayList be shared between methods.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main extends Application {
    private List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Button add = new Button("Add");
        Button display = new Button("Show");

        // Add Items
        add.setOnAction(event -> list.add("Item"));

        // Display Items
        display.setOnAction(e -> {
            printAndClear();
        });

        VBox root = new VBox(10, add, display);
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 200, 200);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private void printAndClear() {
        list.forEach(System.out::println);
        list.clear();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```